# Why is ```on_epoch_end()``` called from several workers on google cloud ml engine?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am running a tensorflow/keras job on ai engine, and have set scale_tier to STANDARD_1. 
This should give me four workers and three parameter servers according to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/machine-types).

My program has:

- Defined callbacks
- My implementation of `on_epoch_end()` write logging information.

I noticed that `on_epoch_end()` is called 8 times for each epoch (probably one master + four workers + three parameter servers), except for the last epoch when it is called only twice.

This seems strange to me as I thought that the parameter servers would coordinate the training, and that the `on_epoch_end()` would be called only once for each epoch.  If I do something in the callbacks at the end of each epoch, will whatever I do be done 8 times?

Any explanation would be very useful.

Comment: AFAIK, Keras doesn't follow the environment variable TF_CONFIG to perform differently on PS and workers. How did you do distributed training with Keras? Did you use tf.distribute.Strategy?

Comment: Thank you very much, this made me look into the documentation more and I see that I have need to do things quite a bit different.